# Angular FormControl values not being displayed on inputs

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
export class CustomerDetails implements OnInit {
  customer: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    initForm();
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.customer = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl("John Doe"),
     address: new FormControl("123 Fake Street")
    });

  }
}
```

Here is my Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="customer">
  <div class="control" formGroupName="customer">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
  </div>
  <div class="control" formGroupName="customer">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="address">
  </div>
</form>
```

I even tried wrapping everything between the form element in an

```
<ng-container formGroupName="customer"></ng-container>
```

But the values of the text inputs are blank.  Am I missing something?

Comment: <input placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" [formControl]="inputControl" />

Comment: You don't need the wrapper `<div class="control" formGroupName="customer">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the wrapper with `formGroupName="customer"` for each form control.

```
<div class="control" formGroupName="customer">
```

Change your HTML form by removing `formGroupName="customer"` as:

```
<form [formGroup]="customer">
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="address" />
  </div>
</form>
```

[Demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uq6ey4?file=src/app/app.component.html)